# What is the least expensive java Joda DateTime update method?

Tags: java, performance, datetime, jodatime

I'm looking to update the time for `DateTime` object. I've noticed that there are two different methods for creating a copy of a `DateTime` object with an updated time, but I'm not sure which to use.

**Is there an advantage of using one of these over the other?**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTime oldTime = DateTime.now()
newTime = oldTime.withMinuteOfHour(30)
```

versus

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTime oldTime = DateTime.now()
newTime = oldTime.minuteOfHour.setCopy(30)
```

Comment: It would be very easy for you to meassure this yourself. Just perform the actions many times and messure the time it takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talking about performance - I don't really bother much, because those 3 lines is almost never going to be a bottleneck in your application unless you're dealing an extreme memory intensive application, where a single extra object might be much of a deal. (Just so you know, I went to the source code, and found out, second approach created an extra `Property` object)

Talking about readibility - certainly I would go with 1st one. Because I've to go to the API to see what `setCopy()` does. First one clearly shows the intent, that it is request a new `DateTime` object, with `minuteOfHour` set to the passed value.

Here's another reason why I would not prefer the 2nd approach. The `minuteOfHour()` method returns a `Property`:

```
Property minuteOfHour = date.minuteOfHour();
```

Now that property can be assigned to any property of `date`. I can later on do:

```
minuteOfHour = date.dayOfYear();
```

That would compile, but changes the meaning of variable without actually changing the name. That means, you won't really know what property you're setting to when you call: `Property#setCopy()`.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the style tips, this helps a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

They are probably about the same - here is the source code for withMinuteOfHour -

```
public DateTime withMinuteOfHour(int minute) {
        return withMillis(getChronology().minuteOfHour().set(getMillis(), minute));
}
```

While minuteOfHour is -

```
public Property minuteOfHour() {
            return new Property(this, getChronology().minuteOfHour());
}
```

So the core of the calls are the same

Comment: Oh, smart to compare the implementations in the source of the calls.